# Image filter for brightness not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css

i try to use some brightness filter on some image when people hover a mouse over it and it work well in chrome but in mozilla it seem not working at all.

Here is the simple CSS i used:

```
.imgsrc:hover {
 -webkit-filter: brightness(120%);}
```

I've already tried couple css that support for mozilla like -moz-filter but my image is just disappear on hover when i use -moz-filter like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that will work in firefox is

```
filter: brightness(1.2);
```

So in your case it would be

```css
.imgsrc:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.2);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

```html
<img class="imgsrc" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZoQ.png">
```